# Can't use breeze even after I added dependencies to build.sbt

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I was following [this](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Installation) tutorial on installing breeze, but I can't get it to work.

My directory structure:

```
myproject/
  build.sbt
  project/
    Build.scala # This is empty
  src/ 
    main/
      scala/
        hello.scala
    test/
      scala/
        my_tests.scala
```

My `build.sbt`looks like this (It is mostly copied from the tutorial):

```
name := "My project"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies  ++= Seq(
  // other dependencies here
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.12",
  // native libraries are not included by default. add this if you want them (as of 0.7)
  // native libraries greatly improve performance, but increase jar sizes.
  // It also packages various blas implementations, which have licenses that may or may not
  // be compatible with the Apache License. No GPL code, as best I know.
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-natives" % "0.12",
  // the visualization library is distributed separately as well.
  // It depends on LGPL code.
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-viz" % "0.12"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  // other resolvers here
  // if you want to use snapshot builds (currently 0.12-SNAPSHOT), use this.
  "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "Sonatype Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
)

// or 2.11.5
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

And my `hello.scala` file looks like this:

```
package mypackage

import breeze.linalg._

object Hello {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hello World")

        val x = Dense.Vector.zeros[Double](5)
        println(x)
    }
}
```

The error that I get looks like this:

```
         not found: value Dense
[error]         val x = Dense.Vector.zeros[Double](5)
[error]                 ^

            ^
```

I know that I adding unit test related libraries to `libraryDependencies` correctly, because my unit tests work after I add them. But what am I doing wrong when adding dependencies for `breeze`? What steps should I take to narrow down the problem?

Comment: It is `DenseVector` not `Dense.Vector`

Comment: @evan058, that was it. Thank You Very Much.

Comment: No problem, have fun with Breeze!